# How to style form with line numbers using CSS Grid Layout?

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

I would like to create a form, which has a line number on each line and several form fields on each line. If the fields don't fit into one line, they should wrap into a new line while the line number stays at the top of the line. Here's an illustration of this form:

[image: Mockup showing how the form should look like]

(The dark blue lines describe the explicit grid areas, the light blue line implicit grid areas for the different form fields.)

I know [CSS Grid Layout](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid-1/) is meant to solve use cases like this, though it is not clear to me, how to generate the form mentioned above with it.

What I've tried so far is:

HTML:

```
<div class="form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="lineNumber">1</div>
    <label for="field1">Field 1 <input id="field1"/></label>
    <label for="field2">Field 2 <input id="field2"/></label>
    <label for="field3">Field 3 <input id="field3"/></label>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="lineNumber">2</div>
    <label for="field1">Field 4 <input id="field1"/></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 30px;
}

.row > * {
  padding: 4px;
}

.lineNumber {
  grid-row-end: line-number span;
}
```

What I don't get yet, how can I achieve to let the row number column span over the whole height of the row while the other columns wrap between lines. I assume it must be possible defining the `line-number` named area using `grid-template-rows`. Though how?

**EDIT:**

I'm aware that it may be possible by using `display: table-row;` / `display: table-cell;`, though my main point is to achieve this using **CSS Grid Layout**.

**2ND EDIT:**

Note that some months after I asked this question here and Grid Layout implementations stabilized showing this feature is not available yet, I [requested it at the CSS Working Group](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/388). Since then a [similar request for spanning explicit and implicit tracks](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2402) was made.

Comment: CSS Grids are ***nowhere*** near ready for production use yet. - http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid

Comment: Nested flexboxes could do it though...probably.

Comment: I know that CSS Grid Layout is not finished yet and that browsers currently currently support it when you enable specific preferences. Though that doesn't hold people from experimenting with it, right? :-) The question is, whether CSS Grid Layout is supposed to cover this use case at all.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, [css counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) should meet your question

```css
@import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css";
form {
  counter-reset: form;  
  border: 2px solid cyan;
}

fieldset { 
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 3em !important;
  border-bottom: 2px solid cyan;
}

fieldset::before {
  counter-increment: form;
  content: counter(form);
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
.sp-b { margin-bottom: 1em }
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 sp-b"><input type="text" class="form-control"></div>
      
      <div class="col-xs-6"><input type="text" class="form-control"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12"><input type="text" class="form-control"></div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12"><input type="text" class="form-control"></div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12"><input type="text" class="form-control"></div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12"><input type="text" class="form-control"></div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: CSS Counters may help, though your solution is missing the point of dynamically wrapping the fields into several lines.

Comment: I don't understand, sorry, do you want an effect like applying `display:block` on each label?

Comment: The point of my comment was that you are separating the fields semantically by putting them into different `<div class="row">` blocks, though they should just wrap visually. Furthermore your example is missing the labels completely and it uses Bootstrap instead of [CSS Grid Layout](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/), which is the main point of my question.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem at this moment. The conclusion, for now, is that the way @SebastianZartner wanted to use grid is not possible in css grids.  Let's hope a future spec of grid will allow us to use span for named area's or lines without a hard start and stopping point. Maybe subgrids will offer a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:table/table-cell` to achieve what you want

#### Snippet

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.form {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.row {
  display: table-row
}
.lineNumber,
.fields {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.lineNumber {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center
}
.fields {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  /*fix inline-block gap*/
  font-size: 0
}
label {
  padding: 0 10px;
  /*whatever you want */
  font-size: 16px;
}
.row:first-of-type label {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block
}
.row:first-of-type label:not(:last-of-type) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  padding-bottom: 10px
}
.row:first-of-type label:last-of-type {
  margin-top: 10px
}
.row:last-of-type .lineNumber,
.row:last-of-type .fields {
  border-bottom: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="lineNumber">1</div>
    <div class="fields">
      <label for="field1">Field 1
        <input id="field1" />
      </label>
      <label for="field2">Field 2
        <input id="field2" />
      </label>
      <label for="field3">Field 3
        <input id="field3" />
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="lineNumber">2</div>
    <div class="fields">
      <label for="field1">Field 4
        <input id="field1" />
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that solves the issue. Though I'd really like to know whether and how this can be achieved using Grid Layout.

Comment: @SebastianZartner wait and see till at least one browser accepts it, there is no idea yet how much will be implemented and how it will be evolving ... just remenber how gradients or flex have seen syntaxe changed before to come usable here and there ;)  flex and css counter could help too http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrmyjv but, yes that was not your question :)